# C# - Switch button event dynamically

Tags: c#

Hy there,

i'm trying to change the button event when the code it's executing. So this is my code:

```
// I will call this function in many places of my code and send a callback function.
// For example, when i click in the confirm button, the event that will be called it's the Callback()
void ShowModal<T>(string Title, IList<T> Data, Func<object, EventArgs, int> Callback)
{
    this.lblTitle.Text = Title;
    this.gvResults.DataSource = Data;
    this.gvResults.DataBind();

    // Executes the sended function when click
    this.lkbConfirm.Click += new EventHandler(
        (object sender, EventArgs e) 
            => Callback(sender, e)
    );

    this.ModalBusca.Show();
}

// I call the ShowModal function
this.ShowModal("Search", data, CallbackSelect);

// This function will be execute
int CallbackSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // my code to execute
    return 0;
}
```

But the `CallbackSelect` function is not called.

I'm using Asp.NET 4.7 web application, thanks!

Comment: Are you really using *Asp.NET 4.7*? That sure looks like code for a client UI framework (like Windows Forms) and not web code. If it's ASP.NET, what is ShowModal supposed to do?

Comment: @Flydog57 If you look closer you will see that the `CallbackSelect` is being passed as a parameter to the `ShowModal` call.

Comment: My ```CallbackSelect``` is being passed as a parameter to ```ShowModal``` method @Flydog57. And yes, i'm using web forms asp.net framework 4.7.

Comment: ```ModalBusca``` it's a ajax ```ModalPopupExtender``` @Leff

Comment: Are you reaching the code that registers the event?

Comment: @jdweng i'm sorry, but i did'nt understand.

Comment: Put a break point on the +=

Comment: @jdweng The new method it's assigned. I've no erros, but the method it's not called on click.

Comment: This is a dynamic function, to define the method dynamically. But I tried to define the fixed method and was unsuccessful.

Comment: callback methods normally have void as return.  See what happens if you make the return value void.

Comment: @jdweng, my desire is to return void, but I was unable to send via parameter with void return.

Comment: EventHandler should look like this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=netcore-3.1